# How to write the class position

Tags: sentence-construction

> My class position is three

or

> My class position is third

In my view, the first one seems to me natural and grammatically correct. Am I right?

Comment: Neither is idiomatic. Use *I am third in my class*. OR *I'm Number 3 in my class.*

Comment: How will I write If I use like in this way:  class position: third

Comment: My two examples are complete sentences, you can write them exactly like I've written them.

Comment: Idiomatically nobody talks about "class *position*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

> I am third in my class.

OR

> My class rank is 3rd.

OR

> Class Rank: 3/200

(if you have 200 people in your class)

OR

> Class Rank: Top 5%